# Comment traduire « footer » dans un contexte sans pagination ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, vocabulaire, terminologie

Lorsque l’on parle d’un simple fichier texte, la traduction de « *header* » en « en-tête » est très bien, mais je n’aime pas traduire « footer » par « pied de page » tout simplement car un fichier texte n’est pas paginé.

Y a-t-il un terme correct en français pour désigner une section d’un fichier qui se trouve à la fin ?

Comment: Pied de page et pagination n'ont rien à voir.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Je pense que [*appendice*](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/appendice) est le terme. Étymologiquement ça colle, même s'il est souvent associé à un groupe de pages fourni en annexe.

Comment: J'aime bien ! Merci.

Answer (score 6):

Je dirais simplement « fin de fichier » ou « fin de document ».

D'autres propositions, utilisées pour les livres, pourraient être (à combiner selon les préférences):

- avant-propos / post-scriptum (ce sont les termes choisis par Georges Perec dans *La disparition*)
- prologue / épilogue
- préambule / postface